# How do I convert a WPF window to a bitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, screenshot

I want to take screen shots of all the windows associated with an application and allow the user to edit them. I am not sure how to convert a window to a bitmap image though.

I want to do something like this...

```
WindowCollection handles = Application.Current.Windows;
List<Image> windowList = new List<Image>();
foreach (Window window in handles)
{
do something here to turn each window into a bitmap
windowList.Add(bitmapFromWindow)
}
```

I have found related questions, but nothing that answers my question. If you find any related resources please post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RenderTargetBitmap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2007/12/02/rendering-ink-and-image-to-a-bitmap-using-wpf.aspx)

or have a look at that one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2007/12/02/rendering-ink-and-image-to-a-bitmap-using-wpf.aspx

Comment: Wow, I don't want to speak too soon, but I think this is exactly what I am looking for and what I want to accomplish.

I want to create a bitmap so I can allow the user to edit it. Ultimately the user will draw all over the window and send them in an http POST.

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead and have a look at the Bitmap-functions...
If I could help you leave a vote up and a "best answer" ;)