# C# ContentControl to Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a `c# WPF` application. Part of this application involves the user moving items around a screen. To do this each item has its own `ContentControl` and it works really well.

I, now however, need to output the content of these **Content Controllers** to a `bitmap`.

I'm creating the bitmap by

```
Bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height)
```

but how do I add the content control output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683542/how-do-i-convert-a-wpf-window-to-a-bitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturescreen to convert your current window to an image:

```
ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
// capture entire screen, and save it to a file
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
Bitmap = new Bitmap(img)
```